# Correctly cancel task from async method when wanting to return early

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a MVC WebApi ApiController that will start multiple async operations, but after awaiting the first one, the logic might no longer be interested in the results of the remaining tasks, and just return.

For simplicity I've made this sample:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test2(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task<ProductSearchResult> searchTask = _productService.SearchAsync("searchterm", cancellationToken);

    // Some sort of logic that means I want to return early, and not wait for the searchTask
    int next = new Random().Next(1, 5);
    if(next <3)
        return Ok("Done");

    ProductSearchResult productSearchResult = await searchTask;

    return Ok(productSearchResult.TotalResults);
}
```

If the code does decide to return early, I see entries of the following in my logs:

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

> System.AggregateException:
> System.NullReferenceException:
> at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.Util.ISyncContext.Enter (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback (System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)

So now my question is: How do I cancel the `_productService.SearchAsync()` call appropriately when I decide to return before awaiting it, in order to avoid that exception?

I don't want to just catch the exception, I want to actively cancel the task before I return. But I do not own the `cancellationToken` in this case.

Comment: Why not do the logic to return early before starting the operation, rather than after?

Comment: How are you passing a `CancellationToken` in to a controller endpoint?

Comment: @Servy In the actual code I have 4 parallel async calls. Then I await the first one, and depending on that result, I might want to just return right away, because I no longer need the other results.

Comment: @Andy The framework automatically add that CancellationToken if it's in the signature.

Comment: @mortenbock In that case the solution is covered by the duplicate, but that's context that really ought to have been in the question from the start.

Comment: So then when would that token get signaled? When the request ends since the controller is transient? That should do it, unless the `SearchAsync` isn't honoring the token.

Comment: @Servy that post does not explain how to cancel the operations? Only how to handle the exception. I basically want to do a call `Cancel()` on the cancellationToken

Comment: @Andy I'm guessing the token from the framework would get cancelled if the http request is aborted for example.

Comment: @mortenbock You can't cancel a cancellation token.  A token is purely a way to tell if an operation has been cancelled.  By design, it exposes no way of causing itself to be cancelled.  You asked how to avoid the exception shown, the duplicate answers that question as asked.

Comment: Try this: Instead of `_productService.SearchAsync` line, do this `var t = Task.Delay(10000, cancellationToken);` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @Servy I updated my question to reflect what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Andy The error is specifically saying that the task returned by `SearchAsync` errored, and went unobserved, so if you replace it with an operation that doesn't error (`Delay` won't have that error) then obviously that won't happen.

Comment: @mortenbock Editing your question into a different question after getting an answer isn't appropriate, but regardless, my earlier comment gives you the answer.  You can't cancel that cancellation token, that's the whole point of a cancellation token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is closed, but try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test2()
{
    using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {
        var searchTask = _productService.SearchAsync("searchterm", tokenSource.Token);

        // Some sort of logic that means I want to return early, and not wait for the searchTask
        int next = new Random().Next(1, 5);
        if (next < 3)
        {
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            try
            {
                await searchTask; // let it gracefully exit since it was cancelled.
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                // swallow this
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // log this
            }
            return Ok("Done");
        }

        var productSearchResult = await searchTask;

        return Ok(productSearchResult.TotalResults);
    }
}
```